# bad java inner classes and lambdas indentation in emacs

Tags: java, emacs, lambda

anonymous inner classes and lambdas are indented wrong for some reason...
That's how it looks like

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    });
```

tab on close why? same with lambdas.

here's my .emacs file:

```
;; fix tabs
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4
              tab-width 4
              indent-tabs-mode t)

;; don't show the splash screen
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; auto close bracket insertion
(electric-pair-mode 1)

;; enable line numbers
(global-linum-mode t)

;; Remove Toolbar
(tool-bar-mode -1)

;; Add melpa to package list
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

;; Start autocomplete
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;; Start yasnipper
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; Load seti theme
(load-theme 'seti t)

;; change font
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "Monaco" :foundry "APPL" :slant normal :weight normal :height 98 :width normal)))))

;; enable line numbers
(global-linum-mode 1)

;; set clipboard to copy
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

Comment: Idk if helpful but https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingJava may be something for you. However you loose a lot of very useful functionality and by that productivity by using a generic editor rather than a full IDE that actually understands Java (and has dedicated formatting options that aren't merely regex based).

Comment: Thanks for reply but already read this page, nothing useful for my problem. yeah you are right i should use intelliJ or eclipse just trying to find something more lightweight i got crappy hardware.

Comment: "wrong" is rather subjective -- what would you like the indentation to look like?

Comment: just don't put tab on end of the inner class "});" here